# Resizing images to a specific height

Tags: php

I've currently implemented a piece of code allowing me to resize images to allow for thumbnails in a gallery I'm creating although it's not going too well.

I'm using some pre-written code to resize the images although I'm struggling with giving the images a minimum of 195px height and 195px width+ staying in proportion if possible.

Also would there be any way of optimising the images allowing page load times to be improved?

Here's my current code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
function imageResize() {
$filename = $row['main'];

if (exif_imagetype($filename) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    $create = imagecreatefromgif;
}

if (exif_imagetype($filename) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $create = imagecreatefromjpeg;
}

if (exif_imagetype($filename) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    $create = imagecreatefrompng;
}

$width = 600; //These values have been tinkered with from their original values
$height = 500;

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($height_orig < 300) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = $create($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
}
```

Comment: Then, what is the problem?
Also `$create($filename)` is a typo? it should be `create($filename)`

Comment: My images aren't appearing at a minimum of 195px also $create is the variable so taking away the $ would cause it to break :) - maybe not the most appropriately name variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out which is smaller in the original image, height or width. If this value is less than your minimum of 195 pixels, set it to this minimum and scale the other value according to the image's original aspect ratio:

```
$minSize = 195;
$aspectRatio = $width_orig / $height_orig;

if ($width_orig < $height_orig) {
    if ($width_orig < $minSize) {
        $width = $minSize;
        $height = $width / $aspectRatio;
    }
} else {
    if ($height_orig < $minSize) {
        $height = $minSize;
        $width = $height * $aspectRatio;
    }
}
```